# Best way to block websites with PowerDNS?

Tags: dns, domain, blocking, internet-filter

I'm working on a DNS filtering system for my household. I have a blacklist from MESD with a list of both IPs and domains, but am not sure how to block them with the blacklist. I thought about using IPSET, but I don't think it'd work with the domains.

Comment: This question will likely get shutdown do to it not being on topic, but try OpenDNS (it's free):  http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home/

Comment: I'm using PowerDNS as a precursor, id much prefer my own solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've flagged this as more appropriate for [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) but will attempt to answer.

You will more than likely need to run your own DNS server on your home network, then alter your DHCP scope to hand that server to your home clients. Any DNS requests would then be routed to that server, which would then consult itself before recursing through to the internet's DNS (my personal vote would go to Google's recursors at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`).

You can find documentation on how to set up a blacklist with Bind (a Linux-based DNS server) [here](http://wordforest.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/set-up-a-dns-blacklist-using-isc-bind/) and [here](http://fnord.no/sysadmin/dns/dns-blacklisting/) - the second link specifically mentioned the MESD blacklist - but YMMV.